# Transition probability of an initial state $i=0$ to a final state $m = 0,1,2,\ldots$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

If the transition probability of a system from initial state $i$ to final state $m$ is 
$$P_{i\to m}(t) = \left|c_m^{\,\lambda}(t)\right|^2,$$
where (to first order)
$$c_m^{\,\lambda}(t) = \delta_{mi} \,+ \lambda c_m^{\,1}(t),$$
then what is the probability of a transition from state $0$ to state $m$, where $m = 0,1,2,\ldots$?

Assume $c_0^{1}(t)=0$ and $c_1^{1}(t)\neq0$. This would mean $P_{0\to 0}(t) = 1$, but also $P_{0\to 1}(t) \neq 0$. I can't make sense of the fact that this would mean 100% probability of the system staying in state $0$ but also some probability of the system transitioning to state $1$.

Surely I must be making an error here, but I can't find information anywhere on $P_{i\to m=i}(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $i\ne m$ the probability to find the initial state $\vert i\rangle$ in the final state $\vert m\rangle$ goes like $\lambda^2\approx 0$ to first order in $\lambda$.